# jquery offset incorrect on floating elements

Tags: jquery, offset

I have a bunch of images each with the `float: left` property applied to them. They are constrained withing a `400px` width area, forcing them into a grid of 4 X 4. If i try to get the position of them, they are always incorrect. What is causing this? You can see what I'm trying to do here: http://dev.redemptionconnect.com/cards/browse. Click one of the images to see what I mean. the dialog that pops up should be over the image you clicked.

Comment: The code in your site is horrendous when I view-source. Try posting the related code directly into the question.

Comment: wow. that is so weird. it's nice and formatted in my source file. one sec

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=1zd1h4TV that's the source file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I see it, you should be checking the offset of the actual floated elements: the underlying `<img>`. They are in fact detached from the inline layout nature of the links when floated, leaving the links at `top:0;left:0`.

You could as well, get rid of the `<a>` and apply that click event to the images. Or `float:left` the `<a>`, whatever your prefer.

Comment: applying the click to the img just allowed for the left position to be correct. the top is still wrong

Comment: A `display:block` to the `<img>` would fix that too. Great it helped!